# What does "Central Europe AG 2006" mean in discharge papers?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two

The discharge papers state

> "Northern France GO 33 WD 45

(which I think I understand),

> Central Europe AG 2006

and

> Rhineland AG 2006.

What do these references mean?

Comment: What is the _[question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/625/1401)_?  I can't start research with "Discharge papers"  (I"m not saying that to be sharp or rude, and I'm sorry if it comes across that way. But the only way to encourage change is to provide feedback).

Comment: These terms were all on the same discharge papers?

Comment: When were these discharge papers issued?

Comment: Im guessing maybe Rhineland AG is the Rhineland Campaign (15 September 1944 – 21 March 1945) And likewise Central Europe was the Central European Campaign (22 March – 11 May 1945) found at - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_Army_campaigns_during_World_War_II   I am not sure what AG or 2006 means.  The Army book shows AG meaning Adjunct General, but I dont think that is correct in your case.

Comment: Hi Jim, and welcome to History:SE.  An image of the relevant part of the document is generally really helpful for providing context in questions like this.

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to be certain without seeing a picture of that part of the discharge papers, but I suspect that it should actually read:

> Central Europe AG 200.6

and

> Rhineland AG 200.6

where the 200.6 are the [Adjutant General's Office decimal file system](https://www.archives.gov/files/research/military/army/ago-supplement.pdf) reference for Badges, citations, decorations, and awards.

This should therefore refer to the Rhineland campaign (15 September 1944 – 21 March 1945) and the Central European campaign (22 March – 11 May 1945).

However, the date that the papers were issued is critical as the Rhineland campaign doesn't appear to be listed as a separate entry in the 1951 supplement linked above.

---

The entry:

> "Northern France GO 33 WD 45"

is more straightforward. "*GO 33 WD 45*" stands for War Department General Order 33, dated 1945. The General Orders of the War Department for 1945 are [available online in PDF format](http://www.benning.army.mil/library/content/Virtual/General%20Orders/GeneralOrders/DAGO1945.pdf).

General Order 33 WD 45 specified the geographical combat zone, and time limitation for the following Bronze Service Star Campaigns related to the European African Middle Eastern Campaign (EAME) medal:

- Egypt-Libya
- Air offensive Europe
- Algeria-French Morocco
- Tunisia
- Sicily
- Naples-Foggia
- Rome-Arno
- Normandy
- Northern France
- Southern France
- Germany
- Ardennes

GO 33 WD 45 was subsequently amended by GO 40 WD 45.  This is of particular importance in your case as GO 40 WD 45 added the Rhineland campaign (changing the name of the campaign from 'Germany' to 'Rhineland'.